# Java how to set subclass tag (field) with a superclass method

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods

I have a class,

```
public class Jo{
    public int objCount = 0;
    private int i = 0;
    public class Property{
        String Tag = new String();
        Jo data;
    }

    public Property propertyArray[] = new Property[12];

    public void add(String St, Jo Obj){
        propertyArray[objCount] = new Property();
        propertyArray[objCount].Tag = St;
        propertyArray[objCount].data = Obj;
        objCount++;
    }
}
```

and a subclass,

```
public class Js extends Jo{
String data = new String();
public Js(String St){
    this.data = St;
}
```

}

I need to set the Tag field of the subclass when I call the add method like this.

```
Jo first = new Jo();
first.add("firsttag", new Js("first string"));
```

But it's not working.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do that

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because the property `Tag` is a member of the inner class `Jo` and therefore can only be accessed by the outer class `Jo`. To make the property `Tag` accessible to the subclass, you have to remove the inner class and add the `Tag` property as a property of the class `Jo`. But, remember, if the `Tag` property is declared as:

```
 private String tag; // note tag not Tag with a capital-letter
```

Then, the `tag` property will not be accessible to the subclass `Js`. You will have to create a setter for `tag` in `Jo` that can be called in `Js`.

Comment: I created the inner class to create an array to keep multiple properties. Are there any other ways to do it? (except ArrayList)

Answer (score 0):

@floydian: Your code works fine so retry running it once again.You should be able to set the tag field of the sub-class using the add method unless the field is marked private. Refer the oracle docs for nested classes tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html